# Why is my Fully Convolutional Autoencoder not symmetric?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am developing a Fully Convolutional Autoencoder which takes 3 channels as input and outputs 2 channels (in: LAB, out: AB). Because the output should be the same size as the input, I use Full Convolution.

The Code:

```
import torch.nn as nn


class AE(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super(AE, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
           # conv 1
           nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

           # conv 2
           nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

           # conv 3
           nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

           # conv 4
           nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

           # conv 5
           nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
           nn.ReLU()

       )

       self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
           # conv 6
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=512, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
           nn.ReLU(),

           # conv 7
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
           nn.ReLU(),

           # conv 8
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
           nn.ReLU(),

           # conv 9
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
           nn.ReLU(),

           # conv 10 out
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=2, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.Softmax()    # multi-class classification

           # TODO softmax deprecated
       )

   def forward(self, x):
       x = self.encoder(x)
       x = self.decoder(x)
       return x
```

The size the output tensor *should* be: torch.Size([1, 2, 199, 253])

The size the output tensor *really* has: torch.Size([1, 2, 190, 238])

My main problem is combining Conv2d and MaxPool2d and to set the correct parameter values in the ConvTranspose2d. Because of that, I treat those separately using the Upsample function for the MaxPool2d and ConvTranspose2d only for Conv2d. But I still have a little asymmetry and I really don't know why.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Just a tip cause I'm on mobile ATM: you can use standard `Conv2d` in decoder as well. When you want to up sample image, you create `Conv2d` layer with at least `in_channel * r^2` channels and use `torch.nn.PixelShuffle` afterwards. This will create an image of shape `(batch, in_channels, width * r, height * r)`. Adjust `r` and `out_channels` of conv however suits you. It's similar to what fastai is doing for their UNet. You would probably get better score that way (less subpixel artifacts during upsampling) and IMO the procedure is easier as well.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke, What exactly is r? And thank you for the reply

Comment: Are the stride and padding parameters shrinking the tensor maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues.

First is insufficient padding: with `kernel_size=5` your convolutions are shrinking the image by 4 every time they are applied (2 pixels on each side), so you need `padding=2`, and not just 1, in all places.

Second is the "uneven" input size. What I mean is that once your convolutions are properly padded, you are left with downsampling operations which at each point try to divide your image resolution in half. When they fail, they just return a smaller result (integer division discards the remainder). Since your network has 4 successive 2x downsampling operations, you need your input to have `H, W` dimensions which are multiples of `2^4=16`. Then you will actually get equally shaped output. An example below

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class AE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AE, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            # conv 1
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

            # conv 2
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

            # conv 3
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

            # conv 4
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

            # conv 5
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            # conv 6
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=512, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),

            # conv 7
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),

            # conv 8
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),

            # conv 9
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),

            # conv 10 out
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=2, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.Softmax()    # multi-class classification
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

input = torch.randn(1, 3, 6*16, 7*16)
output = AE()(input)
print(input.shape)
print(output.shape)
```